# Spectrum color picker HSV to RGB

Tags: colors, rgb, hsv

Hi i'm trying to use this:https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/ colorpicker on my web and it works well but it has one issue - output is hsv that can't be used in css.
Is here any way to change the output to rgb or hsl?

Comment: Here's the [hsv to rgb](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=21#text21) function logic.

Answer (score 3):

Initialise your spectrum call with `preferredFormat` set to `rgb`, `hsl` or `hex`.

https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#options-preferredFormat